# BibTex in ACL formatting

Tags: bibtex

I am writing a paper for a conference that follows ACL formatting, but I have not been able to use the `.bib` file I created which uses the BibTex format for citations. It seems to have its own citation style. I thought BibTex is something that everyone follows. Am I missing something here?

Conference style link: https://emnlp2015-website.herokuapp.com/submissions.html

I am using:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{acl2015}
```

Comment: you might have a better chance of an answer if you gave a link to the conference style or author guidelines

Comment: Thanks for pointing these out. I have added the documentclass and a link to the conference style

Comment: the guidelines clearly allow bibtex and provide a bibtex style file (`acl.bst`) you have given no indication of your input or what error message you got so it  is impossible to help.

Comment: You need `\bibliographystyle{acl}` and a reference to your `.bib` file via
`\bibliography{mybibfile}`, then compile as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/15925.  The template file has these commands commented out and the contents of the compiled bibliography included instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the suggestion from this link: https://clear.colorado.edu/CompSemWiki/index.php/Adding_ACL_Style_Citations
I test it and it works.